# Unable to install "libpq5" and in turn "libpq-dev" and in turn "psycopg2" in linux mint19.3 Tricia

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, fastapi, psycopg2

I tried install "psycopg2" in a python virtual environment in my system using the command

```
python3 -m pip install psycopg2
```

Then I got the response

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/d6/cd8c46417e0f7a16b4b0fc321f4ab676a59250d08fce5b64921897fb07cc/psycopg2-2.9.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1f976zbe/psycopg2/
```

Next I tried installing "libpq-dev" using the command

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

And I had this response below

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 15.1-1.pgdg20.04+1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I have been trying to install libpq5 using different means including going to this [ubuntu package updates site](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/postgresql/focal-pgdg/main/base/libpq5)

But libpq5 refuses to install and keeps telling me I have broken packages. I try to list the packages but nothing comes up, I tried to remove the broken packages using

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

It runs but after it's done and I try to install "libpq5" and "libpq-dev" on my machine It still doesn't work and I still cannot install "psycopg2". Please does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: OK, so what libpq do you have installed/available? `apt policy libpq5` should list them. I will not that you appear to have set up the pgdg repos at some point and it's possible you have priorities set such that you are trying to mix versions between that and ubuntu's default.

Comment: To your question **add as text**. 1) What repo(s) are you using to install the packages? 2) What version of Postgres do you have installed?

Comment: I went for a full reinstall of my system. And the issue went away. Thank you all for your help.